# python code to calculate median for a list as input

Tags: python-3.x

I have the following function:

```
def median(list):
  if list ==[]:
    return []

  elif len(list)==1:
    return list[0]

  else: 
    list= sorted(list)
    length= len(list)+1
    median=0

    if length%2==0:
            median= (list[length/2]+list[length/2-1])/2
    else:
            median= list[length-1/2]    
  return median
```

It gives me an error when I call it like this:

```
median([4, 5, 5, 4])
```

> resulted in an error: list index out of range

PS:I am new to python, please excuse me if this is very basic!

Comment: length = len(list) +1 is adding one to the length. In your example the list is of length 4, but in your code this is turned into 5.

Comment: I recommend you not use `list` as a variable name as it overrides `list()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified your code and tested for a few cases.

```
def median(list1):

   length= len(list1)

   if length <=0 :
       return None
   if (length)==1:
       return list1[length//2] 
   else: 
     list1= sorted(list1)
     median=0

     if length % 2 == 0:
             median= (list1[length//2]+list1[length//2-1])/2
     else:
             median= list1[length//2]    
   return median
```

Kindly let me know if there is something wrong with the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You added 1 to the length of the list here `length= len(list)+1`, this isnt necessary.

If you have a list that looks like `list = [4,5,5,4]` `len(list)` would return 4.

Your code should work properly without this.

Edit: It's probably also best to specify your order of operations:

from things like this: `list[length-1/2]`

to this: `list[(length-1)/2]`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
def median(x):
    if len(x) < 2 : return x if x ==[] else x[0]
    x = sorted(x)
    length = len(x)-1
    return x[length//2] if (length + 1) % 2 else (x[length//2] + x[length//2+1])/2
```

I used `x` since `list` is a function by itself